# Django Crispy Forms CustomLayout with Fieldset

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

So I want to build a custom layout, that extends `LayoutObject` for a form that I have.

```
class NewBookForm(LayoutObject):


    template = 'library/layouts/new_book_layout.html'

    def __init__(self, fields, template=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.fields = fields
        # Overrides class variable with an instance level variable
        if template:
            self.template = template

    def render(self, form, form_style, context, template_pack=TEMPLATE_PACK, **kwargs):
        fields = self.get_rendered_fields(form, form_style, context, template_pack, **kwargs)

        template = self.get_template_name(template_pack)
        return render_to_string(template, {'fields': fields})
```

And I'm calling it using

```
    self.helper.layout = Layout(
            NewBookForm(Fieldset('book_id', 'name', 'author'))
    )
```

Right now Django is saying "template does not exist."
However, this is not getting me the result I'm looking for.

UPDATE 1:

Now that library/layouts/new_book_layout.html has something like

```
<div class="w-40 mr-2">
  {{name|as_crispy_field}}
  {{name.errors.as_ul }}
  {{author|as_crispy_field}}
  {{author.errors.as_ul }}
</div>
```

I'm now getting the error:

```
CrispyError at library/layouts/new_book_layout.html

|as_crispy_field got passed an invalid or inexistent field
```

and highlighted:

```
{{name|as_crispy_field}}
```

Comment: Can you include the stacktrace.

Comment: made the edits to the question to add your issue

Answer (score 0):

That is because once you call `get_rendered_fields` it returns an string object not a crispy object, so instead of using `|as_crispy_field` filter, you should use the `|safe` filter since what your context contains is an HTML string.